# select max(date) within another condition

Tags: sql-server, date, filter

alright, so basically this is my table:

```
order   date
11111   date1
11111   date2
11111   date3
22222   date4
22222   date5
22222   date6
```

ok, so i need my query to output the following:

```
order   date
11111   date3
22222   date6
```

date3 and 6 are the most current for their respective orders.
i managed to filter the most current date, but it would just output the row with the newest date in general, not groupes/ordered by column1.

it returns

```
order   date
22222   date6
```

when date6 is the newest date in the column.

btw i use ms sql server 2012

Comment: Can't you just `select order,max(date) from t group by order`? What would you like done differently?

Answer (score 3):

As [@Alex K has commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111040/select-maxdate-within-another-condition/15111327#comment21262253_15111040), you can use [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177673.aspx) with [aggregate functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) such as [`MAX()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx).

Therefore you can return a result set with the max date per order:

```
SELECT [order], MAX(date) as maxdate
FROM Table
GROUP BY order
```

With your table you would then get the following result set:

```
order   maxdate
11111   date3
22222   date6
```

Comment: `order` will need to be `[order]`